# Closing modal dialog with shared AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Normally to close a bootstrap modal dialog in AngularJS, I simply inject $modalInstance into the controller for the dialog and then call $modalInstance.dismiss().

However, I have a case where I am sharing a controller between 2 views. The first view is never displayed in a modal dialog, and the second view is always displayed in a modal dialog.

I was hoping there was a way to optionally inject the $modalInstance into the controller, but I get an exception when opening the non-modal view that $modalInstanceProvider is not defined. I have also tried gaining access to $modalInstance by injecting $injector into the controller and using:

```
var modalInstance = $injector.get('$modalInstance');
modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
```

But that didn't work, either. The injector cannot resolve $modalInstance in either case.

Is there another way to close the dialog with $modalInstance? Or is there a way to somehow conditionally inject $modalInstance, or close the dialog by triggering some other event (e.g. keypress)?

Comment: I've done similar by using 2 controllers, one modal, one not and moving all my controller functions into a service

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, I may wind up doing that. I was hoping there was something easier, but I'm not opposed to your solution if it's my only option.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this, but it kinda smells.
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCJeaVC1tZ53eDe4gXKj?p=preview)

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
function Ctrl() {
  return function(){
    arguments[0].name = 'World';
    console.log( arguments )
  }
}
var m1 = new Ctrl();
m1.$inject = ['$scope'];
var m2 = new Ctrl(); 
m2.$inject = ['$scope', '$injector'];


app.controller('MainCtrl', m2);
app.controller('Main2Ctrl', m1);
```

index.html

```
<p ng-controller="MainCtrl">Hello {{name}}!</p>
<p ng-controller="Main2Ctrl">Hello2 {{name}}!</p>
```

You'll see they dependencies injected as expect but `argument[I]` does not feel right. I would not recommend to do something as shown. Just go for two controllers using prototype to define common behavior.